# Cómo mostrar una partialview u otra en base a un radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo una vista en la que quiero que:
Por defecto se muestre una vista parcial al entrar en la misma.
Después, según se seleccione una opción con un radio button, muestre una u otra.

Las vistas parciales son: _DirTipoF.cshtml y la que se ha de cargar por defecto, _DirTipoL.cshtml
El código de la vista es este:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   <div class="nav-tabs-top nav-responsive-sm">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-General">General</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="item-General">
            <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                     <label class="form-label">Tipo de dirección</label>
                     <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                           <input name="radio-direccion" value="local" type="radio" checked="checked" class="custom-control-input">
                           <span class="custom-control-label">Local &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                           <input name="radio-direccion" value="foranea" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                           <span class="custom-control-label">Foránea</span>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-row">
                        <div id="direccion"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="text-right mt-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
}

@section Scripts {
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
         $("[name=radio-direccion]").on('change', function(){
            var $radio = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("GetTipoDireccion", "Cliente")',
                data: { tipodir = $radio.val() },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
                   $("#direccion").html(data);
            }
         });
      });

   </script>
}
```

El código del método de la acción es este:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetTipoDireccion(string tipodir)
{
   if (tipodir.ToLower() == "local")
      return PartialView("_DirTipoL");
   else
      return PartialView("_DirTipoF");
}
```

He probado con todos los ejemplos al efecto que he encontrado, pero por algún motivo, parece no llegar a realizarse la solicitud a GetTipoDireccion().

Agradezco cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Comment: Intentaste poner un breakpoint en `GetTipoDireccion(string)` aver si entra al método?

Comment: Juan, sí. Tengo un breakpoint al que no llega al cambiar el checked de los radio buttons. Sin embargo sí que actúa cuando pongo la url directamente

Comment: En la consola de javascript no te produce ningún error? la url que esta generando `Url.Action` es correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré el problema. Era una asignación en un objeto mal realizada.
Concretamente esta:

```
data: { tipodir = $radio.val() },
```

que ha de ser:

```
data: { tipodir : $radio.val() },
```

Gracias a Juan Salvador Portugal que me ha dado la pista de la consola de JavaScript para detectar el error.

Comment: Cierto, y eso es porque en la llamada ajax se enviar objectos json y no variables.

Answer (score 0):

Como estas pasando información desde tu vista al controlador que carga la vista parcial y (supongo) ese valor está fuera de tu tabla de ruteo (/controlador/metodo/{id}), tu llamada debe de ser tipo Post, y el método de acción debe de ser decorado con HttpPost

Llamada ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'@Url.Action("GetTipoDireccion", "Cliente")',
    data: { tipodir: $radio.val() },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
       $("#direccion").html(data);
}
```

Método de acción:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetTipoDireccion(string tipodir)
{...
```

Comment: KodiakMx, he cambiado de GET a POST y continúa igual. Sigue sin funcionar.